# Trivial linked list creation bug using for loop

Tags: c++, loops, linked-list

i am trying to create a single linked list using for loop. I end up creating an extra node with a zero value.

Below is my code:

```
node *insert(node *curPtr) {

     node *temp = new node() // create a temp node
     curPtr = temp;
     for ( int i=1; i < 3; i++ ) {
          temp->data = i;
          temp->next = new node();
          temp = temp->next; 
     }       
     return curPtr;
}

void printList(node *curPtr) {
     while(curPtr) {
     std::cout<<curPtr->data<<std::endl;
     curPtr = curPtr->next;
     }
}
```

I get the following output:

1
2
0

Whereas i am expecting

1
2

What do i need to change in my code?

Thanks

Comment: I see no output statements in your code.  In addition, what debugging have you done?

Comment: Your output should be ` 0 1 2 ` not ` 1 2 0 `

Comment: Your code will actually create 4 nodes, not 2 or 3.

Comment: Edited with output code.

Comment: @interjay, why 4? I'm seeing a loop starting from 1 to < 3, i.e. it will iterate only twice.

Comment: @adripanico The code was edited after my comment.

Comment: @interjay ahhh sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are always making

```
temp->next = new node();
```

So, in the while loop of the `printList` function, there is an extra iteration showing a node that have not been assigned yet and -guess that due a compiler assumption or because you are initializing the value of node.data in the constructor of `node`- you are getting a value equal to 0 for this node. The **quick solution** is to change the print function as following:

```
void printList(node *curPtr) {
  while (curPtr->next) {
    std::cout << curPtr->data << std::endl;
    curPtr = curPtr->next;
  }
}
```

I will prefer to make `curPtr->next = null` until the moment that it will be a real node to insert at the end of the list.

Comment: It would be better to fix the inserting part, than fixing printing of list created in broken way